# Como posso ativar um método na MainWindow de uma outra janela em C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Gostaria que quando eu der um click em um botão em uma janela secundaria seja criado uma nova aba executando um método na janela principal `MainWindow`.
Estou tentando utilizar o código abaixo mas ele gera uma exceção dizendo que o `MainWindow` retornou null.

Mensagem:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Referência de objeto não definida para 
uma instância de um objeto.' 
(... as Projeto.MainWindow) retornou null.
```

Botão da janela secundaria

```
private void Selecionar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            (Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow).CrianovaAba();
        }
```

Método na MainWindow

```
 public void CrianovaAba()
        {
            UserControl Nuser = new UserControl(); // Instancia o UserControl

            ClosableTab theTabItem = new ClosableTab();
            theTabItem.Title = UserControl._Novomaterial;
            theTabItem.Content = Nuser;
            TabControlMaterial.Items.Add(theTabItem);
            theTabItem.Focus();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode injetar sua MainWindow no construtor da janela secundária desta forma:

```
     private readonly MainWindow _mainWindow;
     public JanelaSecundaria(MainWindow main)
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         _mainWindow = main;
     }
```

E depois chamar método através da _mainWindow:

```
    private void Selecionar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _mainWindow.CrianovaAba();
    }
```

Não esqueça de fornecer a MainWindow na instancia da janela:

```
JanelaSecundaria janelaSecundaria = new JanelaSecundaria(this);
```